# Questing about implementing SHA 1 in C++

Tags: c++, cryptography, sha

Hello Im trying to implement SHA 1 using C++ - just for fun and for understanding HASH functions better. I am following a pseudo code I found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1. I am at the main loop where I have to calculate 'temp'. But when I add binary values I am getting numbers larger than 32 bits. There is nothing wrong with my code but is this supposed to happen?

```
For example: 
When I add
11101000101001000110000000101100
and
01100111010001010010001100000001
I get:
01001111111010011000001100101101

but technically it should be:
0101001111111010011000001100101101
```

which is larger than 32 bits. Is this supposed to happen or should I just ignore the bits beyond 32? Or am I doing this completely wrong and stick with HEX like the pseudo code?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You're most likely using a 32-bit platform, with 32-bit ints. As hard as you try to squeeze more bits into your int, the most you'll get is 32 bits. Try using a `long long`, instead.

Comment: The comment in the code you linked to says *"All variables are unsigned 32-bit quantities and wrap modulo 2^32 when calculating"* so they are expected to just wrap round.

Comment: Ahh ok understood. Thanks!

Comment: In the question you say that technically it should be 2 bits larger, but note that you're working with *unsigned* values here. So the extension would be with just `1` instead of `01` - if it *wasn't* modular addition, of course :) In symmetric crypto about everything within the rounds is performed modulo 2^32 or 2^64 depending on the word size.